# Class Validator @ValidateIf() not working properly

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I have the following class in nest js with this class validator:

```
 @ValidateIf(val => val !== '*')
 @IsObject()
 @IsNotEmptyObject()
 queryParams: DbQuery | '*';
```

If I send '*' it returns

```
 [ 'queryParams must be a non-empty object' ]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For who ever finds himself here.

```
@ValidateIf(val => val.queryParams !== '*')
@IsNotEmptyObject()
queryParams: DbQuery | '*';
```

Comment: Does not work, either. I used 

  @IsInt(ALWAYS)
  @ValidateIf(o => o.angle !== 127)
  @Min(-27, ALWAYS)
  @Max(90, ALWAYS)
  @IsOptional(ALWAYS)
  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
  @ApiPropertyOptional({
    type: Number,
    example: 3,
  })
  public angle: number;

Comment: Sry, my mistake was: I forgot to add ALWAYS to validateIf

@ValidateIf(o => o.angle !== 127, ALWAYS)